# Excel 2013 Scatter Chart having trouble with multiple plots with xlMarkerStyleNone?

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot, labview

I am creating a scatter chart in Excel using LabVIEW (same API basically as VBA). In fact I have already done this and it works great in Excel 07. Now that Excel has been upgraded to 2013 these charts are breaking in odd ways. Here is what I have discovered:

I am creating a chart using `AddChart2` with an XlChartType of `xlXYScatter`. I create 3 series from data that is already saved into the Excel sheet. One is intended to be a scatter of data points and the other two are intended to be upper and lower limit lines. Previously the data point series was just set up as a series with MarkerStyle `xlMarkerStyleDiamond`. The two line series are `xlMarkerStyleNone` with a LineFormat of `msoLineSingle` to create the line.

By disabling various bits of code I have been able to trace it down to `xlMarkerStyleNone`. If I set those lines to have no markers, the chart will simply not plot my data point series (although it plots the lines just fine). If I set those lines to have any other marker type, Excel will plot all 3 series, except the limit lines will have markers AND lines at that point which is what I do not want.

Does anyone know of some weird bug or restriction of Scatter charts in 2013 with mixing marker styles or using markerstyle = none? I have also noticed that Excel sometimes (seemingly randomly) tries to "guess" one of my charts types and will plot everything but as a "Scatter and Lines" chart, and not the `xlXYScatter` I specifically programmed it to be. I'm not sure if this is related or not. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: So I see now that whatever marker style I apply to the limit lines, gets applied to the data plot as well, even though the data plot specifically lists its marker style as diamond. This would explain why when marker style was none, the data plot was not appearing...not sure why that behavior is occurring though...

Comment: So, playing with the Index property of the SeriesCollection of each plot seems to have moved behavior around as far as which plots have which styles applied. I am not sure at all why this behavior changed from 07 or why the plots seem to apply behavior from the wrong index. For example I say plot 1 is this set of data make it blue, plot 2 this set make it yellow. But I switch indexes and they both still have the correct data but colors flip. Again, not sure why this behavior is occuring but hopefully it helps someone else debug their problem in the future.